# What is the purpose of thread in tensorflow queue operation?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, queue, python-multithreading

```
images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=32, num_threads=4)
```

I often see a queue created with `num_threads` and the threads are said to be for enqueue operation. I don't quite understand the purpose of setting multiple threads for enqueue, because the way I see it, enqueue is just putting a value at the end of the queue.

Comment: My guess is if you wanted to preprocess the data.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thanks for reply! Do you think the preprocessing can be done through none-tensorflow functions?

Answer (score 1):

From [Threading and Queues tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues):

> For example, a typical input architecture is to use a
>   `RandomShuffleQueue` to prepare inputs for training a model:
>
> - Multiple threads prepare training examples and push them in the queue.
> - A training thread executes a training op that dequeues mini-batches
>     from the queue.
>
> The TensorFlow Session object is multithreaded, so multiple threads
>   can easily use the same session and run ops in parallel.

The idea is that data pipeline is usually I/O intensive: the data may be fetched from the disk or even streamed from the network. It is quite possible for a GPU *not to be* a bottleneck in computation, simply because the data isn't fed fast enough to saturate it.

Reading in multiple threads solves this problem: while one thread is waiting for I/O task, the other thread already has some data for the GPU. When this data is processed, the first thread hopefully received and prepared its batch, and so on. That's why `tf.train.batch`, `tf.train.shuffle_batch` and other functions, support multi-thread data processing. Setting `num_threads = 1` makes the batching deterministic, but if there are multiple threads, the order of data in the queue is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can I say that, the threads will handle data preprocessing (for example from file names to tensors). If it's so, must the preprocessing procedures completely in tensorflow framework? (can I use opencv function to read image file?)

Comment: The idea is to process *tensors* and with tensorflow transformations. But it is possible to apply non-tensorflow functions as well.